# SetItemnumber not working in nested enumeration

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I have typed following code for a frame in beamer presentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\setItemnumber[1]{\setcounter{enumi}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] \vspace{-7 pt} \boldmath
\begin{enumerate}
\setItemnumber{5}
    \item  If $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f(x)=x^2$ for $x=1,2,3$, then 
 
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a]
        \item $f''(x)=2 \;\; \forall \; x \in[1,3] $
        \item $f''(x)=2 \; \; \textrm{for some } x \in (1,3)$
    \end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a]
    \setItemnumber{3}
        \item $f''(x)=2 \;\; \forall \; x \in(1,3) $
        \item $f''(x)=2x \;\; \forall \; x \in(1,3) $
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and got the output

[image]

Now I was expecting bottommost line to enumerate as c and d as I used SetItemnumber{3} but it is showing as a and b. How to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: your document doesn't compile, but beside this: the counter for the nested enumerate is `enumii` not `enumi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested for the second order of enumerated items... use enumii instead:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\setItemnumber[1]{\setcounter{enumii}{\numexpr#1-1\relax}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t] \vspace{-7 pt} \boldmath
\begin{enumerate}
\setItemnumber{5}
    \item  If $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable function such that $f(x)=x^2$ for $x=1,2,3$, then 
 
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a]
        \item $f''(x)=2 \;\; \forall \; x \in[1,3] $
        \item $f''(x)=2 \; \; \textrm{for some } x \in (1,3)$
    \end{enumerate}

\end{multicols}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[a]
    \setItemnumber{3}
        \item $f''(x)=2 \;\; \forall \; x \in(1,3) $
        \item $f''(x)=2x \;\; \forall \; x \in(1,3) $
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{multicols}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also add `\usepackage{multicol}` in the preamble

Comment: What should I do if need to use both second order of enumerated items and third order of enumerated items?

Comment: Try `\newcommand\setItemnumber[2][1]{\ifnum#1=1\setcounter{enumi}{\numexpr#2-1\relax}\else\ifnum#1=2\setcounter{enumii}{\numexpr#2-1\relax}\else\setcounter{enumiii}{\numexpr#2-1\relax}\fi\fi}` .. To use it just use `\setItemnumber[2]{3}` for "second order" or just `\setItemnumber{3}` for first